# How can I make the website sort by price from greatest to smallest

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays

I'm working on a small grocery store website using javascript and I am having trouble sorting the items on the products category from least expensive down to most expensive.

The customer selects the "client" category and chooses their allergen specification, once the specification is selected they have to select the products tab where they will see the list of products, as shown in the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWj3s.png).

As you can see, the products pricing is all mixed up, how can I make it so that the products go from cheapest product to the most expensive product at the bottom.

Code is below:

```js
//groceries.js
// Array of products, each product is an object with different fieldset
// A set of ingredients should be added to products   

var products = [
 {
  name: "brocoli $1.99",
  vegetarian: true,
  glutenFree: true,
  price: 1.99,
  organic:true
 },
 {
  name: "bread $2.35",
  vegetarian: true,
  glutenFree: false,
  price: 2.35,
  organic:false

 },
 {
  name: "salmon $10.00",
  vegetarian: false,
  glutenFree: true,
  price: 10.00,
  organic:true

 },

 {
  name: "chicken $8.99",
  vegetarian: false,
  glutenFree: true,
  price: 8.99,
  organic:true

 },

 {
  name: "macaroni $2.99",
  vegetarian: false,
  glutenFree: false,
  price: 2.99,
  organic:true

 },

 {
  name: "cake mix $3.99",
  vegetarian: false,
  glutenFree: false,
  price: 3.99,
  organic:true

 },

 {
  name: "Jam $4.99",
  vegetarian: true,
  glutenFree: true,
  price: 4.99,
  organic:true

 },

 {
  name: "banana $1.99",
  vegetarian: true,
  glutenFree: true,
  price: 1.99,
  organic:true

 },

 {
  name: "eggs $1.50",
  vegetarian: true,
  glutenFree: true,
  price: 1.50,
  organic:true

 },

 
 {
  name: "apples $2.49",
  vegetarian: true,
  glutenFree: true,
  price: 2.49,
  organic:true
 }

];
 


// given restrictions provided, make a reduced list of products
// prices should be included in this list, as well as a sort based on price

function restrictListProducts(prods, restriction) {
 let product_names = [];
 for (let i=0; i<prods.length; i+=1) {

  
  if ((restriction == "Vegetarian") && (prods[i].vegetarian == true)){
   product_names.push(prods[i].name);
  }
  else if ((restriction == "Gluten Free") && (prods[i].glutenFree == true)){
   product_names.push(prods[i].name);
  }

  else if((restriction == "GlutenFreeandVegetarian") && (prods[i].glutenFree == true) && (prods[i].vegetarian == true) ){
   product_names.push(prods[i].name);
  }

  else if((restriction == "Organic") && (prods[i].organic == true) ){
   product_names.push(prods[i].name);
  }

  else if((restriction == "GlutenFreeandOrganic") && (prods[i].organic == true) && (prods[i].glutenFree == true) ){
   product_names.push(prods[i].name);
  }

  else if((restriction == "GlutenFreeandVegetarian") && (prods[i].vegetarian == true) && (prods[i].glutenFree == true) ){
   product_names.push(prods[i].name);
  }

  else if((restriction == "GlutenFreeandVegetarianandOrganic") && (prods[i].organic == true) && (prods[i].vegetarian == true) && (prods[i].glutenFree == true) ){
   product_names.push(prods[i].name);
  }

  else if (restriction == "None"){
   product_names.push(prods[i].name);
  }
 
 }
 return product_names;
}

// Calculate the total price of items, with received parameter being a list of products
function getTotalPrice(chosenProducts) {
 totalPrice = 0;
 for (let i=0; i<products.length; i+=1) {
  if (chosenProducts.indexOf(products[i].name) > -1){
   totalPrice += products[i].price;
  }
 }
 return totalPrice;
}






// main.js

function openInfo(evt, tabName) {

 // Get all elements with class="tabcontent" and hide them
 tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
 for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
  tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
 }

 // Get all elements with class="tablinks" and remove the class "active"
 tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
 for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
  tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
 }

 // Show the current tab, and add an "active" class to the button that opened the tab
 document.getElementById(tabName).style.display = "block";
 evt.currentTarget.className += " active";

}


 
// generate a checkbox list from a list of products
// it makes each product name as the label for the checkbos

function populateListProductChoices(slct1, slct2) {
    var s1 = document.getElementById(slct1);
    var s2 = document.getElementById(slct2);
 
 // s2 represents the <div> in the Products tab, which shows the product list, so we first set it empty
    s2.innerHTML = "";
  
 // obtain a reduced list of products based on restrictions
    var optionArray = restrictListProducts(products, s1.value);

 // for each item in the array, create a checkbox element, each containing information such as:
 // <input type="checkbox" name="product" value="Bread">
 // <label for="Bread">Bread/label><br>
  
 for (i = 0; i < optionArray.length; i++) {
   
  var productName = optionArray[i];
  // create the checkbox and add in HTML DOM
  var checkbox = document.createElement("input");
  checkbox.type = "checkbox";
  checkbox.name = "product";
  checkbox.value = productName;
  s2.appendChild(checkbox);
  
  // create a label for the checkbox, and also add in HTML DOM
  var label = document.createElement('label')
  label.htmlFor = productName;
  label.appendChild(document.createTextNode(productName));
  s2.appendChild(label);
  
  // create a breakline node and add in HTML DOM
  s2.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));    
 }
}
 
// This function is called when the "Add selected items to cart" button in clicked
// The purpose is to build the HTML to be displayed (a Paragraph) 
// We build a paragraph to contain the list of selected items, and the total price

function selectedItems(){
 
 var ele = document.getElementsByName("product");
 var chosenProducts = [];
 
 var c = document.getElementById('displayCart');
 c.innerHTML = "";
 
 // build list of selected item
 var para = document.createElement("P");
 para.innerHTML = "You selected : ";
 para.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
 for (i = 0; i < ele.length; i++) { 
  if (ele[i].checked) {
   para.appendChild(document.createTextNode(ele[i].value));
   para.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
   chosenProducts.push(ele[i].value);
  }
 }
  
 // add paragraph and total price
 c.appendChild(para);
 c.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Total Price is " + getTotalPrice(chosenProducts)));
  
}
```

```css
/* This style sheet is taken from  https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_tabs.asp> */

/* Style the tab */
.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Style the buttons that are used to open the tab content */
.tab button {
  background-color: inherit;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
.tab button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
.tab button.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <! This style sheet is taken from  https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_tabs.asp>
 <link href="styles/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<h1>Super Groceries</h1>

<body>

<!-- Tab links, each one with an onclick event associated with it -->
<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openInfo(event, 'Client')">Client</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openInfo(event, 'Products')">Products</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openInfo(event, 'Cart')">Cart</button>
</div>

<!-- Tab content -->
<div id="Client" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Client Information</h3>
  <p>Tell us a bit about you.</p>
 Choose a Category:
 <select id="dietSelect" name="dietSelect" onchange="populateListProductChoices(this.id, 'displayProduct')">
 <option value=""></option>
 <option value="Vegetarian">Vegetarian</option>
    <option value="Gluten Free">GlutenFree</option>
    <option value="Organic"> Organic</option>
    <option value="GlutenFreeandVegetarian"> GlutenFreeandVegetarian</option>
    <option value="GlutenFreeandOrganic"> GlutenFreeandOrganic</option>
    <option value="VegetarianandOrganic"> VegetarianandOrganic</option>
    <option value="GlutenFreeandVegetarianandOrganic"> GlutenFreeandVegetarianandOrganic</option>



    <option value="None">None</option>
  </select>
  
 
</div>

<div id="Products" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Your targeted products</h3>
  <p>We preselected products based on your restrictions.</p>
  Choose items to buy:
  <div id="displayProduct"></div>
  <button id="addCart" type="button" class="block" onclick="selectedItems()">
  Add selected items to cart.
 </button>
</div>

<div id="Cart" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Cart</h3>
  <p>Here is your cart.</p>
  <div id="displayCart"></div>
</div>

<script src="scripts/groceries.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/main.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please review [how to ask](https://StackOverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), particularly about minimal reproducible examples. Then `edit` to remove any portion of this code that is not strictly useful to demonstrate the problem. Minimizing the amount of code volunteers must slodge through to determine the issue, and to formulate a solution, helps them efficiently hone in on the problem, and provide an Answer. It also helps future visitors, looking for solutions to their problems, quickly determine if their issue is similar to yours. Concise Q's get more, better, & quicker responses.

Comment: Also, where is your attempt? Is this the original shopping cart code, without any attempt to sort as you want? This reads like you simply want someone else to write the custom code for you. As SO is not a free custom code writing service, please indicate what you tried and why (how you expected that to work), and explain how your results differ from what you expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a new array of product prices (you can also solve without creating a new array , but I solved it so that the solution would be more understandable) and sorted it from the low to the high price:

```
var priceProducts = new Array(products.length);
for (let i = 0; i < priceProducts.length; i++) {
  priceProducts[i] = products[i].price;

}
priceProducts.sort(((x, y) => x - y));

for (let i = 0; i < priceProducts.length; i++) {
    console.log(priceProducts[i]);
}
```

Output :

```
1.5
1.99
2.35
2.49
2.99
3.99
4.99
8.99
10
```